# Why did my reputation go down by around 300 points?

Tags: support, reputation

Why did my reputation go down by around 300 points?

I had around 1463 reputation one day (just a few days ago), and when I came the next day on Stack Overflow I had only 1144 reputation.

Where did all that reputation go?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42658/why-did-reputation-go-down-by-45-points

Comment: hey, stop marking it duplicate. this is the case of more 300 points not only about 45 points. I want a focused answer about why my reputation was decreased?

Comment: It'll be due to a reputation recalculation - read the answer on the question I linked to.

Comment: the answer is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

> Anyway, if you find that your reputation has changed overnight, it might be because we now check for, and remove, any suspicious upvote or downvote patterns.

This is exactly what happened in your case. Note that this doesn't necessarily mean that *you* did anything suspicious – maybe you have a fan that votes you up a lot.

Comment: oh yeah may be, because that was the only day I hit the reputation cap. :) thanks anyway.